# Need alternative to getElementByID to update text box via select onchange event

Tags: javascript

I am creating an array of form elements by copying field in
Javascript. I could not use ID's because the fields are system generated.

What I need is a way to copy the selected text from a drop down and
paste it into the very next `input box`.

My Layout:

```
 (row 1) SELECT | INPUT
 (row 2) SELECT | INPUT
 (row 3) SELECT | INPUT
```

```js
function updateField(e){    
    var selectElement = e.target.value;
    alert(selectElement); 
    // Got it! works fine
    //If I use an id on the input field, it is the same for ALL <tr>'s. 
    //The following line works almost. But it puts it in the top TR only.
    //That over writes what was there from the TR above.
    document.getElementById("SomeID").value = selectElement;   
    //not gonna work for me  
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>   
   <td>
     <select onchange='updateField(event);' name="tom">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
     </select>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input name="sue" value="aaa" />
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>
     <select onchange='updateField(event);' name="tom">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
     </select>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input name="sue" value="bbb" />
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I need to capture the `select box` value and put it in the input box
value of the same `<tr>`.

What I need is a way to pass the retrieved info to next form field
(`input box`) without using any `id` or `class` or such thing. Just a
simply pass this result to the very next form field in the next `td`.
And it can not have an `id` on any `td`, `tr`, `select`, or `input`. Surely
there is a way to grab the next control without specifically
specifying it??

When I manually type different messages into the input fields (which
all have the same name), I get exactly what I want in my `form` post!

PHP Post Results:

```
 $myNumbers = $_POST['sue']; 
 count("$myNumbers") = 1;
 $myNumbers[0] = "aaa";
 $myNumbers[1] = "bbb";
```

But I don't want `"aaa"` or `"bbb"` (typed in vales). I want the items
selected for the individual `rows`.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want you want to do is transverse the DOM tree from your `<select>` element till you get to your `<input>`.

One way you can do this is by using the [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) DOM method to get the parent `<td>` or parent `<tr>`. From there you can find the sibling `<td>` by using [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling), and then the input from there, or find the input from the parent `<tr>` using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

```
var selectElememt = e.target;
var parentTD = selectElement.closest('td');
var siblingTD = parentTD.nextElementSibling;
var inputElement = siblingTD.querySelector('input');
inputElement.value = selectElement.value;

//using parent tr instead
var selectElememt = e.target;
var parentTR = selectElement.closest('tr');
var inputElement = parentTR.querySelector('input');
inputElement.value = selectElement.value;
```

If your structure ends up being different or changed, eg you add another `<td>` or more input elements you will need to change how you transverse the DOM tree to get to your desired input.

Comment: Thanks you Patrick!

It works like a charm!

I am a long way from where I need to go. But this sets me on the correct path! :)